# C++: проверка указателя на null вызывает исключение

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте!

В модуле проекта, являющего частью библиотеки snmp 3.3.8 есть следующий простенький код.

Модуль log.cpp

```
/*------------------------ class DefaultLog -------------------------*/

// define the default logs

AgentLog* DefaultLog::instance = 0;

void DefaultLog::cleanup()
{
  lock();
  if (instance) delete instance;
  instance = 0;
  unlock();
}

AgentLog* DefaultLog::init_ts(AgentLog* logger)
{
  AgentLog* r = instance;
  if (!r)
  {
    lock();
    if (!instance)
    {
#ifdef WITH_LOG_PROFILES
#ifdef DEFAULT_LOG_PROFILE
    initLogProfiles();
#endif
#endif
  if(!logger)
    logger = new AgentLogImpl();
  instance = logger;
    }
    r = instance;
    unlock();
  }
  return r;
}
```

Проект компилируется и билдится нормально, с минимумом варнингов, но при запуске вылетает исключение:

> Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00007FFDA05FDE0E (ntdll.dll) в SNMPClient.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0x0000000000000024.

причем дебаг указывает строку

```
if (!instance)
```

функции

```
AgentLog* DefaultLog::init_ts(AgentLog* logger)
```

В чем может быть дело? Я пробовал заменить это проверкой на null, так то же самое.

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Дебаг не может указывать на `if (!instance)`, скорее ошибка происходит в методе `lock`. Не следует присваивать и сравнивать указатели с 0. Проверка `if (instance) delete instance;` лишняя. Проверка `if (!instance)` после `lock` тоже, так как она происходит за строку до этого.

Comment: Логично в принципе. Только автор этого кода не я, это библиотека snmp++ 3.3.8 версия.

Comment: Можно предположить, что я его неправильно использую...

Comment: @VTT вторая проверка - это реализация паттерна  double checked locking: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Блокировка_с_двойной_проверкой

Comment: У вас this занулился